# Any error in my JQuery code? The lottory can only move one step after click start

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>lottery</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        *{
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
        .container{
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left:0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background: #333;
        }
        .nine{
            position: relative;
            margin: 20px auto;
            height: 300px;
            width: 300px;
        }
        .items{
            background: #eee;
            border-radius: 50px;
            width: 80px;
            height: 80px;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .active{
            background-color: red;
            color: #fff;
            box-shadow: 0 0 16px rgba(33,154,219,.8), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.2) ;
        }
        .btn-start{
            background-color: #3385ff;
            cursor: pointer;
            color: #fff
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <table class="nine">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="items" data-index="1">1</td>
                    <td class="items" data-index="2">2</td>
                    <td class="items" data-index="3">3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="items active" data-index="8">8</td>
                    <td class="items btn-start" data-index="9">start</td>
                    <td class="items" data-index="4">4</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="items" data-index="7">7</td>
                    <td class="items" data-index="6">6</td>
                    <td class="items" data-index="5">5</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var gRunning = false;
        $(".btn-start").click(function(e){
            if(gRunning){
                return;
            }
            gRunning = true;

            next(parseInt(Math.random()*50));
        });

        function next(time){
            var activeItem = $(".items.active"),
                activeIndex = activeItem.data("index"),
                max = $(".items").length -1,
                nextTime = time + 5* time/50,
                nextIndex = 1,
                nextItem = null;

            if (activeIndex = max) {
                nextIndex = 1;
            }
            else{
                nextIndex = activeIndex + 1;
            }

            activeItem.removeClass("active");
            nextItem = $(".items[data-index="+nextIndex+"]").addClass("active");
            if (time>800) {
                gRunning = false;
                var info = nextItem.text();
                alert("Congrats, you got "+ info);
            }
            else{
                window.setTimeout(function(){
                    next(nextTime);
                },nextTime);
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This code stop at data-index:1 after I click the "start" button,then after a while, the alert box will pop up,"congrants, you got 1". any error in the code cause it didn't move forward??? It should be roll several circles then slow down then stop and pop out the alert box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (activeIndex = max) {
```

This is setting activeIndex to max every time, so `nextIndex` will always be 1.

Use

```
if (activeIndex == max) {
```

Comment: oh,yes,that's it..Thx

Answer (score 0):

This is assignment, not comparison:

```
if (activeIndex = max)
```

Use `==`

```
if (activeIndex == max)
```